# Where is the archive files on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, archive

I am learning C from a book. The book mentioned archive files:

> An archive contains .o files
>   Ever used a .zip or a .tar file? Then you know how
>   easy it is to create a file that contains other files. That’s
>   exactly what a .a archive file is: a file containing other
>   files.
>   Open up a terminal or a command prompt and
>   change into one of the library directories. These are
>   the directories like /usr/lib or C:\MinGW\lib that
>   contain the library code. In a library directory, you’ll
>   find a whole bunch of .a archives. And there’s a
>   command called nm that you can use to look inside
>   them.

However When I looked up the lib location(on Ubuntu) that book says, didn't find archive files. 
How can I see these archive files?

Comment: `.a` is a static library. `.so` is a dynamic library.

Comment: /usr/lib /usr/share/lib /lib and their trees although files can also be linked to these folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location of system libraries could change slightly across different distributions. On Ubuntu, you can find the static libraries in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` and `/usr/lib32` for 64-bit and 32-bit respectively (This is, in fact, slightly different in older Ubuntu distros. But on recent distros (>Ubuntu 12), this has been consistent).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the software packages you have installed.

For example, if you install `traceroute`, then you should see something like this in /usr/lib/:

```
# ls -l /usr/lib/*.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22448 Aug 29 12:45 /usr/lib/libsupp.a
```

You can easily make your own library.  For example:

mylib.c

```
int hello()
{
    return 1;
}
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int hello();

int main()
{
    printf("Hello returned: %d\n", hello());
    return 0;
}
```

Execute:

```
$ cc -c -o mylib.o mylib.c
$ ar r mylib.a mylib.o
$ cc -o test test.c mylib.a

$ ./test 
Hello returned: 1
```